# Xpath how to get the value from a node above

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have the following html structure.  The input id value is dynamic. E.g. gwt-uid-150
I am trying to work out an Xpath to get radio button labelled "Comma" so i can click it.

```
<table class="gwt-DisclosurePanel gwt-DisclosurePanel-open" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
            <div style="padding: 0px; overflow: hidden;" aria-hidden="false">
                <div class="content" aria-hidden="false">
                    <span class="gwt-RadioButton block">
                        <input id="gwt-uid-150" type="radio" name="delimiter" value="on" tabindex="0" checked=""/>
                        <label for="gwt-uid-150">Comma</label>
                    </span>
                    <span class="gwt-RadioButton block">
                    <span class="gwt-RadioButton inline marginright">
                    <input class="gwt-TextBox" type="text" disabled="" size="1" maxlength="1"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

If i use the following Xpath I can get the label

```
//label[contains(text(), "Comma")]
```

I would like to get the node above it which is the input id of type radio, as this is the radio button.

I tried using ancestor::

```
//label[contains(text(), "Comma")]/ancestor::
```

How do i do it please?

Thanks,
Riaz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, getting it by label is a good approach here, use [`preceding-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/preceding-sibling):

```
//label[contains(., "Comma")]/preceding-sibling::input
```

Comment: Brilliant, Thank you.